# Holder-continuous barycenter maps

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, geometric-measure-theory, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ be a complete locally-compact metric space.  We define the $p$-barycenter map as a continuous function:
$$
\beta:\mathcal{P}_p(X)\rightarrow X,
$$
which is a right-inverse of the map associating to any $x \in X$ its point-mass $\delta_x\in \mathcal{P}_p(X)$.

It is well-known that, if $X$ is [CAT(0)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAT(k)_space) then $\beta$ can be assumed to be $L$-Lipschitz for some $L\in (0,1]$.  My question is, are there known *(resp. classes of)* examples of metric spaces for which $\beta$ is Hölder continuous but *not Lipschitz continuous?*

Comment: What is the variable $p$ supposed to denote?

Comment: Oh, it denotes the $p^{th}$ Wasserstein space; i.e. $\mu\in \mathcal{P}(X)$ for which $\int_{x \in X} d^p(x,x_0)\mu(dx)<\infty$ for some $x_0\in X$ and with the usual $p$-Wasserstein distance.