# $L^p$-barycenters via continuous selectors

Tags: pr.probability, mg.metric-geometry, optimal-transportation, selection-principles, non-positive-curvature

Let $\mathbb{P}$ be a Borel probability measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $\int_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n} \|x\|^p\mathbb{P}(dx)<\infty$.  For which $p\in [1,\infty)$ (other than $p=2$) is the following optimality set non-empty:
$$
X(\mathbb{P}):=\left\{
x\in \mathbb{R}^n:\, \int_{u \in \mathbb{R}^n}\|u-x\|^p\mathbb{P}(du)=\inf_{x'\in \mathbb{R}^n}
\int_{u \in \mathbb{R}^n}\|u-x'\|^p\mathbb{P}(du)
\right\}.
$$

More importantly, for which such $p$ does there exist a continuous selector $S:\mathcal{P}_p(\mathbb{R}^n)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ with:
$$
S(\mathbb{P})\in X(\mathbb{P})
?
$$
Note, here, we equip $\mathcal{P}_p(\mathbb{R}^n)$ with the $L^p$-Wasserstein distance.

This question is related to [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/397420/holder-continuous-barycenter-maps).

Comment: I submitted an edit to the post: $2^{\mathbb{R}^n}$ should be $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbb{P}(du)$ is missing under the integration signs when you define $X(\mathbb{P})$.
I will sleep on the latter question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There exists a minimizer for all $p\in [1,\infty[$. To see that, let $R > 0$ be big enough so that
$$
\int_{B_R(0)}\|u\|^pd\mathbb{P}(u) > \frac{1}{2}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\|u\|^pd\mathbb{P}(u).
$$
Then if $x > B_{3R}(0)$, we see that
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\|u-x\|^pd\mathbb{P}(u) > \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\|u\|^pd\mathbb{P}(u)
$$
and hence is
$$
\inf_{x\in\mathbb{R}^n}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\|u-x\|^pd\mathbb{P}(u) = \inf_{x\in B_{3R}(0)}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\|u-x\|^pd\mathbb{P}(u).
$$
Now, just note that $x\mapsto \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\|u-x\|^pd\mathbb{P}(u)$ is continuous so it attains a minimum on the compact set $B_{3R}(0)$. Moreover, we can say that the minimizer is unique since the function is convex (that follows from the convexity of $x\mapsto \|x\|^p$).

Comment: Can we obtain a positive answer for the snowflaked version where $p\in (0,1)$?